# ASP.NET Web Forms get current user email and assigning data on user identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm building a Web Forms website that uses the ASP authentication and two databases to store data. When a user registers it creates records on both these tables, this is my register.aspx C# code:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        infoLicencia.license_activations++;
                        res_users regUser = new res_users
                        {
                            branch_gkey = infoLicencia.branch_gkey,
                            licence_gkey = infoLicencia.license_gkey,
                            activo = true,
                            fecha_registro = DateTime.Now,
                            email = user.Email
                        };
                        db.res_users.Add(regUser);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        // Para obtener más información sobre cómo habilitar la confirmación de cuentas y el restablecimiento de contraseña, visite http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                        //string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                        //string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                        //manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirmar cuenta", "Para confirmar la cuenta, haga clic <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aquí</a>.");
                        signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                    }
```

This works fine, but now I need to retrieve the data stored on the other database and make it available for the user session.

I have tried this on IdentityModels.cs:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que authenticationType debe coincidir con el valor definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar reclamaciones de usuario personalizadas aquí
            var Database2 = new PPublicEntities();
            var UserData = Database2.res_users.Single(i => i.email == Email);
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("BranchId", UserData.branch_gkey.ToString()));

            return userIdentity;
        }

        public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
        }

    }
```

But this Email property is null, I need the current user email to search for its data on the other database. I thought this Email property was filled on login, I really don't know what to do, also why all claim values must be String? I really wish it could be a long type.

Answer (score 0):

By default user email not added to user claims during authentication. We have to explicitly add this as below snippet.

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.EmailClaimType, "User Email", ClaimValueTypes.String));
```

You can also write a small method to retrieve current user claim information. For email :

```
public static string GetCurrentUserEmail()
        {
            var userEmail = string.Empty;
            var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
            var userEmailClaim = claimIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == IdentityConstants.EmailClaimType);

            if (userEmailClaim != null)
            {
                userEmail = userEmailClaim.Value;
            }
            return userEmail;
        }
```

You might want to take a look at a library I created at : [GitHub](https://github.com/rahulgarg1985/CodeNode.Identity)

Comment: Im a newbie on asp net, what does Constants.EmailClaimType do? And that method where is declared? On IdentityModels or somewhere else?

Comment: Constants.EmailClaimType could be any constant string. I declared it as "ASP.NET.UserEmailClaim" ,so that same can be used when we read from user claims. I created a complete library over identity framework and this method is declared there. I already shared GItHub repo address above. You can find this and other method in IdentityClaimsHelper.cs class. let me know if you want to know anything else.